# android: call a number

Tags: android

i am working in android.

i want to call a number which is displaying in textbox. this is my code in xml file:-

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView_event_place_contactNo"

            android:text="Contact No"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

             android:textColor="#000000"

            android:textSize="10dp"

            android:phoneNumber="true"  android:autoLink="phone"/>
```

and this is my code:-

```
      textView_contactNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9783506635"));

                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }

            });
```

This above code is working properly. But problem is this , whenever i click on contact number then that call window opens, even if i dont want to call that number and press back button then also my call is connecting.

So please tell me what should i do for this, so when i press back button then call should not connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your intent type to `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```

Using this intent type you have choice of calling or not calling that number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the call is not ending because the call manager is hiding in background when you press the back key...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an  setOnClickListener.The property `android:autoLink="phone"` will do all the work